# How to correctly compose Invoke-Expression command to build variable value based on config file values

Tags: windows, powershell

**Please see latest code that is now working, there is no longer any need for any Invoke cmdlet:**

```
$ClassificationList = $null
$classifications = $null
$ClassificationList = $ConfigFile.Settings.Project.Classifications

If ( $ClassificationList )
{
    $ClassificationList = $ClassificationList -replace ',','|'

    $classifications = $wsus.GetUpdateClassifications() | 
    where title -match $ClassificationList

    $updatescope.Classifications.Clear()
    $updatescope.Classifications.AddRange($classifications)
}
```

**Original Question:**

*This question has been condensed to avoid confusion.*

When executing the below code:

```
$ScriptText = 
@"
`$classifications = `$wsus.GetUpdateClassifications() | 
        ?   {
                $_.Title -eq 'Critical Updates' `
                -OR `
                $_.Title -eq 'Security Updates' `
                -OR `
                $_.Title -eq 'Definition Updates' 
            }
"@
$scriptBlock = [Scriptblock]::Create($ScriptText)
Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock {$scriptBlock}
Write-Host $classifications
```

The variable $classifications does not get populated, but executing the code without wrapping it into a script block works fine.  I am trying to read from a config file all classifications I want to search WSUS for and dynamically add them to the above script, but executing that script when it is built does not appear to work, though no errors are thrown.

Comment: The correct way to compose `Invoke-Expression` is to [not use it in the first place](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2011/06/03/invoke-expression-considered-harmful/). Your code looks like you want to use `Invoke-Command`.

Comment: Hi Ansgar, thanks for the help.  I have modified it to use Invoke-Command, but still don't seem to get any value in the $classifications variable.

Comment: Please [edit] your question. Code in comments is unreadable.

Comment: I have added it along with my other update to the question.  
What I am trying to achieve is the equivalent to dynamic SQL, but in Powershell.

Comment: You could probably just say `$ClassificationList = $ClassificationList -replace ',','|'`.

Comment: True, I have amended to this, saves me one more line of code thanks!

Comment: I don't think you have to add extra quotes around it either.

Comment: Very true, I just tested it live for the first time and it only showed security updates, but when removing the extra quotes it showed all updates for each classification in the config file.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do it this way.

```
$wsus.GetUpdateClassifications() | 
  where title -match 'critical updates|security updates|definition updates'
```

Comment: EDIT: How do I mark this as the answer please? EDITEDIT: Found it! Thanks again. 
Thank you for this answer, it works perfectly!
The only odd thing is it only works with Invoke-Expression, not Invoke-Command, however this doesn't affect my use of this script, so happy to mark this as the answer and up vote (I have only just joined Stack Overflow, so my up votes don't count publicly unfortunately).

Comment: Why do you need to use invoke-expression or invoke-command?  Couldn't you make this a function?

Comment: I am reading a config XML file to pull out all the classifications specified and need to build the script dynamically depending on the contents of the config file.  However I now realise the method you gave me no longer requires me to build the string, since I can now simply use: $ClassificationList = $ClassificationList -split "," $ClassificationList = $ClassificationList -join "|".  I will add this code as an update to my question for anyone who has a similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

Don't define your code as a string and then put that string in a scriptblock.

```
Invoke-Command -Scriptblock {$ScriptText}
```

If you must create a scriptblock from a string you'd do it like this:

```
$ScriptText = "if ( 1 -ne 2 ) {
    Write-Host 'Hello'
} else {
    Write-Host 'GoodBye'
}"
Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock ([Scriptblock]::Create($ScriptText))
```

However, normally you'd create the scriptblock as a literal, either as a variable

```
$scriptblock = {
    if ( 1 -ne 2 ) {
        Write-Host 'Hello'
    } else {
        Write-Host 'GoodBye'
    }
}
Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock $scriptblock
```

or inline

```
Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock {
    if ( 1 -ne 2 ) {
        Write-Host 'Hello'
    } else {
        Write-Host 'GoodBye'
    }
}
```